# what is the way to show category wise product in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

controller.php

```
$shop['product'] = Product::with('ProductImages')->where('product_status','=',1)->where('product_drop_status','=','no')->where('language_code','=',$translate)->orderBy('product_id','desc')->get();
```

index.blade.php

```
 @foreach($categories['display'] as $category)
         <div class="container pt-3 mt-3 pb-3 mb-3">
          <div class="row">
          <h4 class="black mb-2 pb-2">{{ $category->category_name }} {{ $category->cat_id }}</h4>
          <div class="swiper-container"> 
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">  <!-- ok -->
                           
                            @php $z = 1; @endphp
                              @foreach($shop['product'] as $product) 
                                <!-- display products -->

                           @endfoeeach
```

i want to show category wise products.but it shows all product
what should i try??

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby because Eloquent uses the query builder internally, so you can do

```php
GroupBy("categoryWise")
```

Comment: try this one
$shop['product'] = Product::with('ProductImages')->where('product_status','=',1)->where('product_drop_status','=','no')->where('language_code','=',$translate)->orderBy('product_id','desc')->groupBy("product_category")->get();

Comment: it's working .products are coming group wise.it's ok .products are shown in one category.but i need to show in different category.` ``By the way thank you```

Answer (score 0):

You should have write query like below:

```
$shop['category'] = Category::->whereHas('Product', function($query) use($translate){$query->where('product_status','=',1)->where('product_drop_status','=','no')->where('language_code','=',$translate)->orderBy('product_id','desc')->with('ProductImages');})->get();
```

Comment: Error:BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method ZigKart\Models\Category::Product()